# Do native English speakers say "Aladdin touched his fingers on the ring”?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Watch [this story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbxrzaoTCZY) on youtube, they say “**Aladdin touched his fingers on the ring**” at 4:12.

It seems that the people read that story are native English speakers.

I checked variety of dictionaries and it seems none says "**touch your hand/finger... on something**" but rather "**touch something with your hand/finger...**"

But people actually say that in a poem [Cifra Club - Sylford Walker - Golden Pen](https://www.cifraclub.com.br/sylford-walker/golden-pen/letra/imprimir.html)

"*You got to touch your finger on Jah golden pen*"

Do native English speakers say "**Aladdin touched his fingers on the ring**”?

**Note**: I suspect the script of the video above was written by non-native speakers or near-native speakers ad therefore their English is not perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct - most native English speakers would say "Touched the ring with his fingers", rather than "Touched his fingers on the ring".

Sylford Walker is a Jamaican singer, so English is likely not his native language. Those lyrics suit the Jamaican/reggae dialect as well. An example of this is No Woman, No Cry by Bob Marley - the grammatically correct way of saying this would be "No, woman, don't cry".